# Including libcurl in C project

Tags: c, libcurl

This is my very first C program and I'm using this example libcurl code from their website:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://google.com/");

#ifdef SKIP_PEER_VERIFICATION
        /*
         * If you want to connect to a site who isn't using a certificate that is
         * signed by one of the certs in the CA bundle you have, you can skip the
         * verification of the server's certificate. This makes the connection
         * A LOT LESS SECURE.
         *
         * If you have a CA cert for the server stored someplace else than in the
         * default bundle, then the CURLOPT_CAPATH option might come handy for
         * you.
         */ 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
#endif

#ifdef SKIP_HOSTNAME_VERFICATION
        /*
         * If the site you're connecting to uses a different host name that what
         * they have mentioned in their server certificate's commonName (or
         * subjectAltName) fields, libcurl will refuse to connect. You can skip
         * this check, but this will make the connection less secure.
         */ 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
#endif

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So in xcode I created a "group" called it curl and added all the files in the curl directory:
[image]

And now I'm getting these Build errors:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Any advice would help, thanks!

Comment: You should add libcurl as a library, not as a bunch of files

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am using XCode, I can't seem to find an "Add Library" I can see Add Existing Files and Add Existing Frameworks, could it be one of those?

Comment: No idea, I don't know XCode :-( Sorry

Comment: I'm curious, what do you use for your C projects? Is Xcode not very good?

Comment: I just don't use a Mac.  For my C projects I mainly use either just naked makefiles and and editor (ie no IDE at all), or Netbeans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mac OS X comes with a copy of libcurl, so your application doesn't need its own copy.

You didn't mention the version of Xcode you're using. The following applies to 3.2, but may not work in 4.

To use the version of libcurl provided by the system, go to `Project`, then `Add To Project`. In the dialog that comes up, type `/usr/lib` and press enter. Find `libcurl.dylib` in the list of files and click `Add`.

Comment: so when I go to my terminal i can ls in /usr/lib and see libcurl.dylib, but my open dialog when I go to Add to Project cannot find it, even if I search the whole system for that filename

Comment: I copied it to the desktop, and included it there, gotta love Mac :) cheers mate!

Comment: The Mac hides /usr in Finder and the file selector dialog by default, but when you type a '/' in the dialog it gives you a way to open directories it normally won't let you see.

Comment: I may have a different version of OS X or Xcode (10.6.7 and 3.2.4 64 bit respectively) but I don't have anywhere to type the "/" in my dialog other than the search box in the top right. My "Directory selector" is a drop down, nowhere to type anything

Answer (score 4):

For Xcode 4.5:

1. Click on the project in the left pane.
2. Click on the target.
3. Go to the "Build Phases" section.
4. Under "Link Binary with Libraries", click the plus sign.
5. From there you should be able to search for "libcurl.dylib".

Now when you build it should be able to link to the library.

Answer (score 1):

For XCode 7, just right click on the project or group you want to put the lib in, then select `Add Files to "Project Name"...`, and finally find the `libcurl.dylib` in `/usr/lib` directory.